# How do I pass an environment variable into a .sql file?

Tags: postgresql, docker, environment-variables

I'm setting environment variables in a Dockerfile which I want to reference in a `.sql` file. That file is in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` since `initdb` will run it.

How can pass an environment variable? (e.g. `SELECT * FROM $myEnvironmentVariableHere;`)

Comment: if you want that variable to run on `select` then it has nothing to do with `sql` file, but with `SYS ENV`

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways of doing this, but the easiest may be to use a simple shell script with a HEREDOC:

Here's the script, called in scripts/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

psql << EOF
SELECT * FROM $MYVAR LIMIT 1;
EOF
```

Here's how to run it:

```sh
docker run --rm  --name test_pg -v $PWD/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -e "MYVAR=pg_class" postgres:latest
```

Among the various startup messages, you'll see the following lines:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sh
   relname    | relnamespace | reltype | reloftype | relowner | relam | relfilenode | reltablespace | relpages | reltuples | relallvisible | reltoastrelid | relhasindex | relisshared | relpersistence | relkind | relnatts | relchecks | relhasoids | relhasrules | relhastriggers | relhassubclass | relrowsecurity | relforcerowsecurity | relispopulated | relreplident | relispartition | relrewrite | relfrozenxid | relminmxid |           relacl            | reloptions | relpartbound
--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------------+------------+--------------
 pg_statistic |           11 |   11319 |         0 |       10 |     0 |        2619 |             0 |       16 |       398 |            16 |          2840 | t           | f           | p              | r       |       26 |         0 | f          | f           | f              | f              | f              | f                   | t              | n            | f              |          0 |          562 |          1 | {postgres=arwdDxt/postgres} |            |
(1 row)
```

Comment: I want to run the .sql file from inside my container (e.g. `psql -U user -d database -a -f file.sql`)

Comment: Why does it have to be a sql file and not a bash file running inside the container?

Comment: So I can do `psql -U user -d database -a -f scripts/test.sh`?

Comment: No, the call to psql is in the script.